# Pattern Matching Ordering

Tags: f#, pattern-matching

The following piece of code works, but to me it seems wrong... Or maybe it's just my poor understanding of F#... The thing that has me stumped is the ordering of the match in check match function.

```
open System

type Adapter =
    { IP : string
      MAC : string
      FriendlyName : string
      ID : int }

let (|IsMatchByName|_|) (input : Adapter) (name: string) =
    match input with
    | {FriendlyName = friendlyName} when friendlyName = name -> Some()
    | _ -> None

let checkmatch (record: Adapter) (name : string) =
    match name with 
    | IsMatchByName record -> "Match"
    | _ -> "No match"

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv = 
    let testRecord = {IP ="127.0.0.1"; MAC ="FF:FF:FF:FF:FF:FF"; FriendlyName = "Home";ID = 229229}
    let result = checkmatch testRecord "Home" 

    Console.WriteLine(result)
    Console.ReadKey() |> ignore
    0 // return an integer exit code
```

Below is what I would expect the check match function to look like. Where I am matching on the record and passing the name in as an additional parameter.
The first input of IsMatchByName is an Adapter so why does it expect the inputs in the other order?

```
let checkmatch (record: Adapter) (name : string) =
    match record with 
    | IsMatchByName name -> "Match"
    | _ -> "No match"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a direct consequence of partial application.
You're partially applying `record` to `IsMatchByName` ; getting a function which expects a string given by the match clause.

It looks even worse when the partial active pattern returns something (not unit) ; see [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233248.aspx#Anchor_3) for exemple.